# Make image in div slide from right to left loop

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the image from right to left and loop it (by sliding it). Currently, the image isn't showing up in the browser. This is the code I was testing:

Html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
<div class="imgslide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.imgslide {
background: url(images/image.png);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 300%;
animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes slideshow {
0%    { left: 0; }
100%  { left: -200%; }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used that to place other images. In other sections, I don't have this issue. And I placed the image and had it show up by creating a section that wraps around both divs and setting the background-image to that image. But if I set that background of "imgslide" to my image it doesn't appear.

Comment: And to confirm this I went and added the "./" and nothing changed

Comment: ok, then instead of giving the width and height in %, give it in px or em. If this also doesn't work, delete the overflow:hidden; from the slideshow to check if the image is there and if it is hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped. Here is what I did: I changed to em, removed "overflow: hidden" from slideshows. In html, I wrapped everything in <section> and added "position: relative" "overflow hidden" there and set the size of the container here as well. Again thanks!

Comment: Np, please do give my answer a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving the width and height for the .imgslide as a percentage, give it in px or em. You could also delete the `overflow:hidden;` from the `.slideshow`.

This will show if your image is not appearing or if it is appearing and being hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the picture because your containers have no width and height definitions. Here is your code with size definitions.

```css
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Here is where you set a size so it will be visible. */
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.imgslide {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  100% {
    left: -200%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="imgslide"></div>
</div>
```

However, I want to suggest a change. Since you have a background image, why not simply set the animation to the background itself and not the container?

```css
.imgslide {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="imgslide"></div>
</div>
```